# How do I center a Bootstrap Card Image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

How do I center an image in a Bootstrap 4 card? It's a vertical image and it looks wrong being left-aligned. I've been reading the Bootstrap Card documentation and can't find anything about centering the image.

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card col-sm-3">
    <div>
      <img class="card-img-top" src="image_URL" alt="alt-text" >
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="card-text">
            text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: please reference the question it was duplicated from